# Reset a numeric sequence after deleting a row

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a list of users with following data:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user    | sequence |
+----+---------+----------+
|  2 | dave    |     1    |
|  3 | sam     |     2    |
|  4 | harry   |     3    |
|  5 | sarah   |     4    |
+----+---------+----------+
```

If I delete user harry, I would like to re-order the sequence column to give me the following:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user    | sequence |
+----+---------+----------+
|  2 | dave    |     1    |
|  3 | sam     |     2    |
|  5 | sarah   |     3    |
+----+---------+----------+
```

I have tried the following:

```
SET @i = 0;
UPDATE users
SET `sequence` = @i:=@i+1
ORDER BY `sequence` ASC;
```

If I run this using MySQL Workbench it works. However when run via PHP method [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) it is failing with the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`.

It works if I run the statements separately. Is this a safe method - is it open to problems? Is there a workaround or a better way to write the statement?

The application is not using mysqli so I can't use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: There should never be a need to do this, unless you're making false assumptions about the significance of the id; and it can cause real problems if you have relations that use the id as a foreign key

Comment: @MarkBaker the sequence value is only used to display to the user so I thought it would be okay

Comment: It really isn't a good idea..... and it shouldn't matter whether values are sequential without gaps or not..... it only matters that there is a single unique id for each id..... and trying to change that behaviour to ensure that there are no gaps and that all values are sequential inevitably causes problems

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you try a multi_query. You could use perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php or try to seperate it. In this case I would put it inside a transaction, then it should be safe. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

Comment: I should have mentioned but the application doesn't use mysqli - is there anything solution?